# What's the best automation tool for VC++ based project? 

Tags: visual-c++, automation

What's the best automation tool for VC++ based project?

Comment: What do you want to automate?

Comment: actually want to automate a flow of test cases using Excel based framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider http://experitest.com. It's very easy to operate and can export code to any programing language.